# Поменялся путь загрузки библиотек после go mod init

Tags: golang

Пробую работать с go mod.
Пытаюсь создать новый файл go.mod в проекте. Пишу `go mod init github.com/username/http-rest-api`. 
Выдает ошибку:

> go: modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go
>   help modules'

Почему модули запрещены внутри GOPATH/src? Не понимаю.

Пишу в терминале:

```
export GO111MODULE=on
```

После этого файл go.mod создается.

Командой `go get github.com/sirupsen/logrus` скачиваю библиотеку logrus

В go.mod добавляется зависимость:

```
module github.com/username/http-rest-api

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2
)
```

но когда пишу в коде:

```
import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)
```

выходит ошибка:

```
cannot find package "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus (from $GOROOT)
    /home/sergey/work/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus (from $GOPATH)
```

в GOPATH действительно нет этой библиотеки. Лежит она вот тут:

```
$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen
```

Возможно, так и должно быть. Но как мне сейчас импортировать библиотеки? Кто-нибудь может объяснить что я делаю не так?

Comment: добавил командой go mod vendor папку vendor в проект. И все зависимости добавились в эту папку. В принципе так наверное и должно быть при работе с зависимостями. Кажется я начал понимать)

Comment: Рекомендую почитать: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules.  А также обновиться до 1.13.  В каждом релизе есть улучшения системы модулей.